# PHP date_diff give weird results

Tags: php, date, datetime, diff

Simple question can somebody explain what is happing in the code below.

Why are the results different?

```
var_dump(date_diff(new DateTime('2017-12-02'), new DateTime('2018-02-02'))->format('%R%d'));

var_dump(date_diff(new DateTime('2017-12-01'), new DateTime('2018-02-01'))->format('%R%d'));

//dumps string(2) "+0" string(2) "+1"
```

Comment: [I get the same results for both](https://eval.in/894603)

Comment: Same results here as well; tested in 5.5, 5.6, and 7.0

Comment: [Giving different results here](https://3v4l.org/TEn52) but if I [force the timezone to UTC, then they match](https://3v4l.org/KMi7G).... so what's your timezone setting?

Comment: Might be a PHP bug. Any timezone that's positive gives +1 for the 2nd string while any negative or 0 timezone gives +0 for the second case. Here's [what I've tried](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2d03cf34b388bf7705746bdf5245091e6f2ca963)

Comment: Thanks for the fast support.
Im getting the +1 in "Europe/Amsterdam" timezone.

Comment: That would fit, Amsterdam is UTC+1

Comment: All positive timezones seems to be adding 1 day in this case but i still dont know why.

Comment: While i'm on this subject.
Can anyone explain this?
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d656ca30805bf2e19b399fd7e2734b7e63fd439